# Why Date/Time outputting "undefined" in node.js console?

Tags: javascript, date, time

I'm attempting to get time to update with JavaScript in a Node.js console, in my function indexActiveTime I gather the hours, minutes, and seconds, and input them to a console.log that is suppose to output them as the current system time in a formatted 00:00:00; I call the function at the end and run the node.js program and for some reason I only get the following output.

```
undefined:undefined:undefined

undefined:undefined:undefined

undefined:undefined:undefined
```

I've attempted to throw it into certain variables, different concat methods, and the only results I've received are it outputting as the variable, like so.

```
${callActiveHours}:${callActiveMinutes}:${callActiveSeconds}
```

or

```
function getHours() { [native code] }:function getMinutes() { [native code] }:function getSeconds() { [native code] }
```

```js
function addZero(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + 1;
    return i;
  }
}

function indexActiveTime() {

  var getIndexTime = new Date();
  var callActiveHours = addZero(getIndexTime.getHours);
  var callActiveMinutes = addZero(getIndexTime.getMinutes);
  var callActiveSeconds = addZero(getIndexTime.getSeconds);
  console.log(callActiveHours + ":" + callActiveMinutes + ":" + callActiveSeconds);

  var activeTimeOut = setTimeout(indexActiveTime, 500);
}

indexActiveTime();
```

Comment: Hint: `addZero` doesn't always return something. Also you're not passing numbers to it. Also look into the difference between accessing properties and calling methods.

Comment: for addZero I noticed that I was putting + 1 instead of + i. I'll read up on properties and methods.

Comment: You have one console.log that comes after 4 (4!!) separate function calls. I'll grant you the first one to the Date constructor, but why don't you test `addZero` on it's own rather than trying to figure out by guesswork why it isn't working? I guarantee you'll be surprised at what it does... multiple times.

Comment: You're passing a references to methods rather than calling them, so the *if* condition fails in the *addZero* function and it returns *undefined*. Change `getIndexTime.getHours` to `getIndexTime.getHours()`, same for the other methods. And fix the *addZero* function to return *i* if the test fails.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest:

1. The *addZero* function returns *undefined* when the condition `i < 10` is false
2. The assignment `i = '0' + 1` should be `i = '0' + i`
3. It's being passed a function reference rather than the result of calling a function so it's always false (and always returns *undefined*).

```js
function addZero(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
  
    // Fix assignment
    i = "0" + i;
    return i;
    
  // Return i if condition is false
  } else {
    return i;
  }
}

function indexActiveTime() {
  var getIndexTime = new Date();
  
  // Call methods, not just reference them
  var callActiveHours = addZero(getIndexTime.getHours());
  var callActiveMinutes = addZero(getIndexTime.getMinutes());
  var callActiveSeconds = addZero(getIndexTime.getSeconds());
  
  console.log(callActiveHours + ":" + callActiveMinutes + ":" + callActiveSeconds);

  var activeTimeOut = setTimeout(indexActiveTime, 500);
}

indexActiveTime();
```

For how to create a timer that reasonably reliably runs at the required interval, see [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050455/universal-looping-countdown-timer-for-a-web-page/11052696#11052696) answer.